Importing one Swift Package into another
I'm trying to do a very simple thing, but unsuccessfully - I'm trying to create two Swift packages: PackageA and PackageB. I'm trying to put PackageA as a dependancy to PackageB. I've created Package.swift:
let package = Package(
    name: "PackageB",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "PackageB",
            targets: ["PackageB"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Add the local PackageA dependency
        .package(path: "../PackageA")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "PackageB",
            dependencies: [
                "PackageA"
            ]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "PackageBTests",
            dependencies: ["PackageB"]),
    ]
)

I'm getting an error "No such module PackageA" when i try to import it into PackageB. Both packages are stored locally. Also, PackageA has 0 dependencies (empty package with 1 function). If anyone has idea why it doesn't work I will be grateful. Thanks :)
I've tried all variations with adding name to dependencies and it doesn't help.
I've also tried to add platform and minimum version.
It is visible from SS that package isn't properly loaded (SnapKit which is has a small arrow that indicates that I can open it and see content while my doesn't have).



@sonle I've literally created two new packages. I didn't modify Package.swift in the first one and put "public func test()" in it. In second one I've put code which is above. File structure and all other stuff is intact. On disk I have folder projects in which both are saved.

Close all  Xcode windows and ONLY open the  package that needs them both.

Jesus, it works ... Never would have guessed by myself! Thanks a lot @lorem ipsum

Does this answer your question? How to correctly add local Swift Package to Xcode 15 project to see and use its content?

It gets a lot of people, you can edit the child package in "package dependencies" on the left. You should see an arrow now like the one "SnapKit" has in your image.
